How to create odata and non-odata endpoint in same controller
Goal: Within the same controller create two httpget endpoints: one for OData and one for non-OData.
This code gives error: AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
[Route("api/products")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{

  // OData enabled endpoint
  [EnableQuery]
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult GetAllProducts()
  {
    var products = _repo.GetAllProducts();
    return Ok(products);
  }

  // Non-OData enabled endpoint
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult GetAllProducts()
  {
    var products = _repo.GetAllProducts().ToList();
    return Ok(products);
  }


Adding the [NonAction] attribute fixed the problem. Is there a better way?
[EnableQuery]
[NonAction]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAllProducts()
{
    var products = _repo.GetAllProducts();
    return Ok(products);
}


The NonAction attribute prevents a method from being invoked as an action, even if it matches routing rules. instead you need to use the code which can distinguish these two methods from each other.
You could try below code:
[Route("api/products")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _repo;

    public ProductsController(IProductRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    // OData 
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("odata")]
    public IActionResult GetAllProductsOData()
    {
        var products = _repo.GetAllProducts();
        return Ok(products);
    }

    // Non-OData 
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAllProducts()
    {
        var products = _repo.GetAllProducts().ToList();
        return Ok(products);
    }
}


Thanks for the suggestion. My first try was adding the odata to the route. This worked but the odata route becomes /odata/odata/products and /api/odata/products. The solution I propose the odata route is only /odata/products
